# Coloring 3d model Vuforia Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, vuforia

I want to implement a feature in which color of a particular area will be picked by 3d model. I am using vuforia and unity3d and successfully implemented the target detection. In next step I want to pick color of image and put that color on 3d Model.

Many people have already implemented this but I am not able to find a complete tutorial of that.

I have tired to use region Cature as well but no success.

Answer (score 3):

I would take the area of the screen you are after, then place it in a Pixel array and average that array.

```
public Color GetColorFromScreen(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(x, y, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    Color [] pix = tex.GetPixels(x, y, width, height);
    float r,g,b,a;
    foreach (Color col in pix){
        r += col.r;
        g += col.g;
        b += col.b;
        a += col.a;
    } 

    r /= pix.Length;
    g /= pix.Length;
    b /= pix.Length;
    a /= pix.Length;
    return new Color(r,g,b,a);
}
```

Then you grab the material of your model and apply that color

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = GetColorFromScreen(x,y,w,h);
```